# VBA script to parse a multiline input from user

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA script for an Excel document. Here is what I am wanting to happen.

1. The user clicks on a button to Add a new Client to a list.
2. A popup instructs the user to copy a link in another program and paste it in the text field provided.
3. The Client's name is added to the bottom of the list and the name is a hyperlink to the client's online profile.

**Needed Information**

The link that is copied from the other program is automatically formatted like so:

`FirstName LastName
<link_to_client_in_program>`

So the link prints out the Client's first name then last, then on the next line prints out a hyperlink to the client's online profile nested within the carrot brackets.

I have the working code up to this point of where the User gets prompted to add the link, though the text field where the user can paste the link does not show multiple lines, so it only shows the Client's first and last name.

**What I Need Help On**

- Show the Client's Name and the link after the user pastes it into the
  input box.
- Upon the user clicking "OK", the script should parse the inputted text to capture the first name and last name as a variable, and the link to the online profile as a separate variable.
- Then I would like to look through the table on the sheet to find the line following the last added Client and add the Client's name in that cell and make that name a hyperlink to the online profile.

**My Current Code**

```
Sub addClient()
   Dim clientInfo As String
   Dim clientName As String
   Dim clientURL As String

   clientInfo= InputBox("Click on the 'Copy a Link' in CRM for the Client and paste in the field below.", "Client Information")
   clientName  = Left(clientInfo, Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("<", clientInfo) - 1)
   clientURL  = Right(clientInfo, Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("<", clientInfo) - 1)
   Range("B7").Value = clientName 
End Sub
```

**Errors**

When I run the script and click the button the popup happens and I paste the link into the text box provided. When I click "OK" I get an error that says, "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Find property of the WorksheetFunction class".

**How To**

- How do I search through the table and get the next cell in the column 'B' that does not have a Client's data?
- How do I fix this parsing problem?
- How do I paste the data in the correct cell and make it a hyperlink to the Client's URL?

Comment: Why don't you try [**UserForm**](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html) instead of simple inputbox. This way you can do what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, a userform is more flexible and will help you achieve your desired custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this to do an efficient `Find` - which is not the same as the Worksheet Function `Find`

This looks in column A (bottom up), for the last match on cell B7.

If it finds a match it adds the contents of B7 to that cell in A (so you will need to tweak it a little for your purposes).

```
Sub UpdateMe()
Dim rng1 As Range
If Len([b7].Value) > 0 Then
Set rng1 = Columns("A:A").Find([b7].Value, [a1], xlFormulas, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        rng1.Value = rng1.Value & " " & [b7].Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Client not find", vbCritical
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "No value to find", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Find` will return a `1004` error when the target is not found in search text. Take a look at what your input box is receiving into `clientInfo`. I would bet you that it's not including the "<" when the link is pasted.

As for your other questions:

The way I'd find the first available cell in column B is:

```
Do Until Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,2).Value = ""
    i = i+1
Loop
Set rClientTarget = Range(Cells(i,2).Address)
```

And using the macro recorder produced:
`Sheets("Sheet1").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rClientTarget, Address:= "http://www.stackoverflow.com", TextToDisplay:="asdf"`